# How to send email notification bfquiz plus?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I am using **bf quiz plus** plugin for Joomla.
Now i had sent an email notification to the user who give the test quiz. So one email notification is sent to the user.

Now there is by default `from` field for email is set which is  `<admin@joomla3.abs.com>`

So I want to set this from field for email notification to `donotreply@guru99.com`

i have searched this on internet and on the documentation of **bf quz plus** but did not find any help. You can check here which plugin I am talking about - http://www.tamlynsoftware.com/products/bf-quiz-plus.html

And here you can check which from field I am talking about - http://screencast.com/t/3apKCJWm2fo3

So how to do this.

Please help

Comment: Why don't you contact the developer of **bf quiz plus** plugin?

Comment: Then why this website is created?? Is it for helping begginer or only for show

Comment: Yes, it is to help. It's to help with coding related matters. Seeing as you've provided no code, it's considered off-topic. Also, this issue is regarding a 3rd party extenion. Any developer that develops an extension for Joomla, usually provides support. It will also be quicker for you to ask the developer as they will know the code back to front ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one thing. Just search for the  email in the files and replace it with your ID.